# Not consistent executions in Step Function running lambdas function

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have lambdas functions that run Rust code in a docker image, I chain those lambdas in a step function with a map state to run in async way.

The code in the docker file is implemented in async manner too ( read file, write, process and so on)
mainly the code is reading file from s3, process and write it back into s3 as a parquet files.

While i run each lambda separately from the lambda UI i face no issues.

But when I'm running the step function that chain all those lambdas i face an errors that i can't understand what causing them.
Those error are not consistent which mean some executions can Succeeded and some to fail.

Step function definition:

```
{
  "Comment": "Step function for proccess",
  "StartAt": "Process All",
  "States": {
    "Process All": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "ItemsPath": "$.items",
      "ItemSelector": {
        "item_name.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value",
        "lambda_a_payload.$": "$.lambda_a_payload",
        "lambda_b_payload.$": "$.lambda_b_payload",
        "lambda_c_payload.$": "$.lambda_c_payload"
      },
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "step a",
        "States": {
          "step a": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "lambda_a_arn",
            "InputPath": "$",
            "ResultPath": "$.lambda_a_result",
            "Parameters": {
              "item_name.$": "$.item_name",
              "bucket_source": "source",
              "bucket_target": "target",
              "prefix_source.$": "prefix_source",
              "prefix_target": "prefix_target",
              "args.$": "$.lambda_a_payload"
            },
            "Retry": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "Lambda.ServiceException",
                  "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                  "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                  "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
              }
            ],
            "Next": "step b"
          },
          "step b": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "lambda b arn ",
            "InputPath": "$",
            "ResultPath": "$.lambda_b_result",
            "Parameters": {
              "bucket_source": "source",
              "bucket_target": "target",
              "prefix_source.$": "source prefux",
              "prefix_target": "target",
              "item_name.$": "$.item_name",
              "args.$": "$.lambda_b_payload"
            },
            "Retry": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "Lambda.ServiceException",
                  "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                  "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                  "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
              }
            ],
            "Next": "step c"
          },
          "step c ": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "lambda c arn ",
            "InputPath": "$",
            "ResultPath": "$.lambda_c_result",
            "Parameters": {
              "bucket_source": "source",
              "bucket_target": "target",
              "prefix_source.$": "source prefix",
              "prefix_target": "target prefix",
              "item_name.$": "$.item_name",
              "args.$": "lambda_c_payload"
            },
            "Retry": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "Lambda.ServiceException",
                  "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                  "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                  "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
              }
            ],
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "Next": "StartCrawler"
    },
    "StartCrawler": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "crawler name "
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:startCrawler"
    }
  }
}
```

Errors that failed the executions:

```
1) 

{
  "errorType": "&alloc::boxed::Box<dyn core::error::Error + core::marker::Send + core::marker::Sync>",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot get object output"
}

2) 

thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Failed to flush write: ObjectStore { source: Generic { store: "S3", source: PutRequest { source: Error { retries: 0, message: "request error", source: Some(reqwest::Error 

* this error have some more info of path which i deleted - but file is existing.
```

I expecting the step function the run all the chained lambda without any error.

I thought about limit the maxconcrency of the step function to process each item at a time, this still gave me un consistent executions.

P.S

I don't think its issue with code because when i run the lambdas it's didn't failed even once.
Maybe im missing something about step function and how its share resource at each execution.

Hope someone have any idea how to solve this issue or some one faced with this problem.

Thanks alot!

Comment: I suspect this has to do with high concurrency. The error message appears to indicate a failure on Put request to S3 with retries of 0. It could simply be that you are throttled by S3 and that you don't have retries either in the SDK Call to S3 or in the Step Functions state machine Task.

Comment: Hey @JustinCallison,

Thanks for the response. so if i will add some error exception handling its should work ? 
how much time should i wait in such error ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Another question is why this fail only on step function but when calling lambdas from boto3 client every thing going as expected ? 
Is there some limitations with step function and lambda invokation? 
Thanks